# Integration and Tonelli's Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f$ be a nonnegative continuous function on $R$. We define $\psi(t) =m(\{x: f(x)>t\})$ for $t\geq 0$.  I want to show that $\int_0^\infty \psi(t) \, dt$ exists and equal to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx$.

Please note that our integration is the Lebesgue integral. Intuitively I can see that the conclusion holds, and basically it's a consequence of the definition of the Lebesgue integration. I might be wrong.

Also, note that the given function is measurable because it's continuous. I've seen somewhere that this equality is called the distribution formula. Is it a standard theorem? Anyway, can we prove this result using the Tonelli theorem? I guess Tonelli's theorem will work. Can you please give me a little hint? Thanks so much.

Comment: The integral is the area under the curve....

Comment: Yes, that's my thought.  How can I formally prove it? Thank you.

Comment: Consider the characteristic function of the set of points between the curve and the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thanks. It helps.

Comment: See my edits to this question for proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key step is to write $\psi(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \chi_{f(x) > t} \;dx$ where $\chi_{f(x) > t}$ is $1$ if $f(x) > t$ and $0$ otherwise. Then when you swap the order of integration, you get

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty \chi_{f(x) > t} \;dt\, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \;dx. $$

Just think about each step carefully.

Comment: Thanks so much. O' God it was so straightforward. Thanks again.

Comment: Trevor, since we're applying Tonelli's theorem, we have to show that the preimage of the indicator function is measurable in the product sigma-algebra. We can assume that we've Borel sigma-algebra on $R^2$. So, we need to show that the preimage of the indicator function is a Borel set. In fact, It's the upper half-plane ie $\mathbb{R}\times (0, \infty)$, which is clearly a Borel set. Am I correct?

Comment: I think my last argument is not correct.  The set is not a rectangle.

Comment: Functions don't just have one preimage. You need to input any measurable set, or some special measurable sets that generate the sigma-algebra. Since indicator functions only have 2 possible outputs, we just need to look at the preimage of $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$; the empty set and $\{0,1\}$ will obviously produce a measurable set. We also only need to look at one of these, since the preimages are complements of each other. The preimage of $\{1\}$ is $\{(x,t) : f(x) > t\}$ which is measurable since $f$ is a measurable function. @MMM

Comment: I know that the set $x$ is measurable for any $t$ because of the measurability of $f$. How do I know that {(x,t):f(x)>t} is measurable in $R \times R$?

Comment: @MMM that set is the area under the curve $y = f(x)$. There's a theorem you can look for that says that if $f$ is integrable, then the region under its curve is measurable and the measure of that region is equal to the integral of $f$.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll look at the theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^{\infty} \psi (t)dt=\int_0^{\infty} \int I_{\{x: f(x) >t\}}(x) dx dt=\int_0^{\infty} \int I_{\{x: f(x) >t\}}(x) dt dx= \int f(x)dx$ because $\int I_{\{x: f(x) >t\}}(x) dt $ is the length of the interval from $0$ to $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks so much. Thank you.